# Python: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable when trying to update based on calendar entry

Tags: python, tkinter, calendar

Ive looked at many examples but cannot figure out how to fix my issue.

Ive got a calendar date picker from tkinter. When selecting a date it is calling a function to  calculate age from date entry. After calculating, I want it to update variable 'age' so that it can display correct age every time a new date is picked from the calendar. The method works when loading the frame as it takes the initial set date as the date of birth but it wont display the correct age. Also won't work when selecting any other day for the 1st time (2nd time input) it is giving the following error:

```
line 1892, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Global Variables

```
ageSelection = tkinter.StringVar()
age = 0
```

Calendar Picker

```
calPicker = DateEntry(studentInfoRightFrame, selectmode="day", year=2024, month=2, day=7, date_pattern="yyyy-mm-dd", textvariable=ageSelection)
calPicker.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=0)
ageSelection.trace('w', getAge(date.today(), calPicker.get_date()))'
```

Age Label to show age:

```
ageLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoRightFrame, text=age, font=('Calibri', 20))
ageLabel.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=0)
```

Method to calculate age (method works 1st time around, when laoding calendar picker which uses 2024-02-07 as the date of birth)

```
def getAge(today, dob):
print(today)
print(dob)
dob_result = str(dob)
dob_data = dob_result.split("-")
year = int(dob_data[0])
month = int(dob_data[1])
day = int(dob_data[2])

print(year)
print(month)
print(day)

age = (today - date(year, month, day)).days
age = age / 365
print(age)
age = round(age)
ageSelection = round(age)
print(round(age))
```

Full Trace Call:

```
2024-02-09
2014-02-07
2014
2
7
10.01095890410959
10
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback message.

Comment: From the error we know that `self.func` is `None`. But you haven't shown the full traceback so we don't know where this came from. With the full traceback, you could see which line in your code breaks. You could look back from there to see why this `func` is None. Is it something you should have passed in?

Comment: @JohnGordon, tdelaney, I have updated the full trace as it appears in my console

Answer (score 2):

I believe this line of code is the problem:

```
ageSelection.trace('w', getAge(date.today(), calPicker.get_date()))
```

The second argument to `trace()` is supposed to be a callable function.

The way you have it coded, you are calling `getAge()` immediately and using its return value as the second argument to `trace()`.

But `getAge()` does not return anything, so it returns `None` by default.  So `trace()` receives `None` as its second argument, which results in the error.

I think perhaps you are supposed to pass the `getAge` function itself as the second argument to `trace()` so it can be called later when it is needed, instead of calling `getAge()` immediately and passing its return value as the callable.

Comment: Hi John, ain't I passing 'getAge' as the callable function with 2 parameters, date.today() as today and calPicker.getDate() as date of birth which is what I have set up getAge to take? getAge is only trying to set the value to a variable not return anything.

Comment: No, you are not passing `getAge()` as the callable function.  Because you have parentheses `( )` after getAge, you are **calling** it immediately, and then passing its **returned value** as the callable function.  It's equivalent to this code: `print(sqrt(4))` This calls `sqrt(4)` immediately and passes its return value of 2 to `print()`.

Comment: Could you give me a better way to code what I am trying to do here? You see the method I am trying to call and the dates I am trying to pass.

Comment: Yes, I see what you are trying to do.  But I don't know how to do it.